# UNIX tr command query

Tags: unix, tr

Need help converting the below two strings into the required output using Unix tr or any other shell command:

```
String1 = "cn=svc_stack,ou=Service Accounts,dc=ausco,dc=com,dc=au"
String2 = "R@7$g#ft21Yr"
```

into the following result:

```
resultString1 = "cn\=svc_stack,ou\=Service\ Accounts,dc\=ausco,dc\=com,dc\=au"
resultString2 = "R@7$g\#ft21Yr"
```

Comment: `tr` isn't the right tool. You want `sed`.

Comment: Why do you need to escape the `=` signs with backslashes? What's the context here? Why are you modifying source code with a shell script?

Comment: Can you be clear on what you want to process as text? Is `String1 = ` part of the text, or are you just using that in your question to indicate the strings that are in a file, or what?

Comment: I'm using the shell script (User interactive script) to write the LDAP credentials into Jetty server-override cfg file. Due to the "=", " " and "#" characters present in the LDAP credentials, the cfg is not getting read correctly by the server during the startup. 
Hence the need to escape these characters.

Answer (score 1):

So you need a script that escapes an `=` character?

```
sed 's/=/\\=/g' file
```

It's not a good use case for `tr`, which is usually used for replacing single characters with other single characters (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: hard to know if that is unwanted behaviour or not given OP's description

Comment: Apologies for the incomplete context. I'm trying to write the strings into a property file which will then be read by a web container (Jetty server). 
I believe sed would've been a good option if I wanted to escape all the "=", " " and "#" characters in the property file (That's my limited knowledge on sed :-)). 
However, I want to escape these characters only in the value part of the property file (Not in the keys).
Does that make sense? The below sed code doesnt seem to work . Am I doing it wrong? 

mystring=echo "$mystring" | sed 's/\([=# ]\)/\\\1/g'

Answer (score 1):

This will do `=`, , and `#`. You can add other characters, too.

```
sed "s/\([=# ]\)/\\\1/g" file
```

Or to do a string, `echo $String1 | sed ...`, etc.

Comment: The below code doesnt change the mystring variable with a value "cn=svc_stack,ou=Service Accounts,dc=ausco,dc=com,dc=au".

mystring=echo "$mystring" | sed 's/([=# ])/\\\1/g'

Anything wrong there?

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

mystring=$(echo "$mystring" | sed 's/\([=# ]\)/\\\1/g')